# Submitting a form and refreshing the page without adding the refresh into navigation history

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a small web-app on Flask and I've encountered a rather tedious issue with navigating back to previous page.

What I've tried:

- Not navigating away from the page - content is outdated
- Redirecting to the same page back - navigating back is broken (as the action is carried out again)
- Using JS and making the link execute `document.history.go(-2)` or `document.history.go(-1)` - causes issues with CSP (so far I've managed to do without JavaScript at all), multiple edits that are made cause navigating back end up on the same site which is bad UX (I could keep a counter but that doesn't fix the next issue with this approach), it also keeps the page in the navigation history, mucking up going forward
- Keeping a track of all pages visited and generating the back link based on it - causes the url to accumulate junk, also causes issues with too long URLs and them being unsuitable for sharing between users.

So it all dwells down to those form POST actions being troublesome. Is there a way I can **just** refresh the page (but redirect to error page if needed)?

Comment: Not sure I understand what exactly you are having trouble with... You can just refresh the page without adding to the history stack with `window.location.reload()` not sure how you plan on handling errors so cant help there

Comment: What might be an option is to manually post using Ajax when the form submit button is pressed. In the success function, do as @bm_i suggests with `window.location.reload()`, and in your error function you just direct the user to an error page or pop something up on the screen or handle it as you see fit.

Comment: @MichaelCurry I have to investigate how to switch to using Ajax, but are there no options other than Ajax?

Comment: Instead of having an action on the form you should simply have a click handler in your JS for that button.

If you're using jQuery that's super simple, although it's easy enough in vanilla JS as well. I'm sure there are other options, although Ajax is the easiest, at least it would be for me. I'll write an answer that should give you a rough idea of how to do it with Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML include a barebones form with all your inputs setup as normal.

```
<form id='example-form'>
    <!-- inputs here... -->
    <input type='submit' id='form-submit-button'></input>
</form>
```

Then in your JS write a handler for this, I've written it using jQuery below

```
$('#form-submit-button').on('click', function() {
    $.post('example.domain.com/formSubmit', $('#example-form').serialize(), function() {
        //success - do whatever you need to do here
        window.location.reload();
    }
}).fail(function() {
    //error - you can redirect your user to an error page here or whatever
    alert('error');
});
```

I haven't tested this so I apologise if it doesn't work off the bat - check out the jQuery docs for more info on jQuery ajax functions, once you start writing them they get a lot easier.

Handling DOM events - https://api.jquery.com/on/

Sending Ajax calls - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I probably won't start using jQuery, but this definitely gave me an idea how to solve this problem once and for all. Thanks!

Comment: No need for jQuery - check out this site, I just use it because it's something I've used for years and it's always been readily available in my work: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/